# is there a way to create a class injector token from a string?

Tags: angular

I can do:

`injector.get(SomeClass);`

but if I do:

```
const token = new InjectionToken<any>('SomeClass');
injector.get(token);
```

I get: `NullllInjectorError: no provider for InjectionToken SomeClass!`

Is there a way to turn a string into a class injector token?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create an **InjectionToken** from a string in order to resolve a class using the Angular dependency injection system.

```
import { InjectionToken, Injector } from '@angular/core';

function getClassToken(className: string): InjectionToken<any> {
  return new InjectionToken<any>(className);
}

// Usage
const className = 'SomeClass';
const classToken = getClassToken(className);

const instance = injector.get(classToken);
```

getClassToken function takes a string **className** as input and returns a new **InjectionToken** based on that string. You can then use this token with the injector to retrieve an instance of the corresponding class.

Please note you need to ensure that there is a provider registered for the given InjectionToken with the Angular dependency injection system. Otherwise, you will encounter the NullInjectorError you mentioned in your question.

Hope it's helpful.